# How can I compare two fields of a model in a query?

Tags: django, filter, compare, aggregate-functions

I'm writing a management command which will filter a product's original price with suggested prices.

I have a product model which looks like :

```
class Suggestion(models.Model):
    ....
    price = models.IntegerField()

class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    suggestions = models.ManyToManyField(Suggestion)
```

I want to filter all products whose price is equal to minumum suggestion. Something should like :

```
Product.objects.filter(price = minumum(suggestions))
```

AND

I want to filter products where the suggestions contains the Product's original price. Something should like :

```
Product.objects.filter(price__in = self.suggestions)
```

The problem is I can't use a for-loop to look each Product's minumum suggestion and as you guess I can't use object's **self** either, so how can I compare two fields of a model in a query ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F
Product.objects.filter(price__in=F('suggestions'))
```

Comment: Thanks! That works nicely. Yet, there's a small error: suggestions must be in quotation marks inside F('suggestions').

Comment: how about two F? for example two annotated fields?

Answer (score 2):

- `Product.objects.filter(price = minumum(suggestions))`

`suggestions` is not a field on Product (and the columns passed to `F` should have quotes, like `F('suggestions')` not `F(suggestions)`).  So that's no good.

The raw SQL for this is something like this, which joins onto a subquery that gets the minimum price for every product, then filters the list down to those products whose price == the min price.

```
SELECT * FROM product
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT _products_suggestions.product_id, MIN(price) as min_price
     FROM suggestion
     RIGHT JOIN _products_suggestions
     GROUP BY _products_suggestions.product_id
     ) AS min_suggestions ON min_suggestions.product_id = product.id
  WHERE product.price = min_suggestions.price
```

You cannot perform (as of 1.4) a custom join in this way using the django ORM.  You will need to use a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

- `Product.objects.filter(price__in = self.suggestions)`

`self.suggestions`, assuming we are *in* a `Product` instance method, is not a list, so far it's a `RelatedSetManager`.  I doubt, though, that you want to get all the products that have one of the suggested prices of the *current* (aka `self`) product.  That seems odd.

What it sounds like you want is a list of products that have a suggestion that matches *one* of the suggested prices.

You'll need raw SQL again. :-/

```
SELECT * FROM product
  LEFT JOIN _products_suggestions ON _products_suggestions.product_id = product.id
  LEFT JOIN suggestion ON _products_suggestions.suggestion_id = suggestion.id
  WHERE suggestion.price = product.price
```

That would do it, I think.  `RIGHT JOIN` might be faster there, I'm not sure, but anyway you'd end up with a list of products and suggestions that have the same price.