# How to filter using gte of a attribute of corresponding model object in django

Tags: python, django, database, model

```
  bar_1 = models.IntegerField()
  bar_2 = models.IntegerField()
```

1. Filter all values where bar_1<=bar_2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare two fields of a model in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054159/how-can-i-compare-two-fields-of-a-model-in-a-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with an [**`F`**-object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F

MyModel.objects.filter(bar_1__lte=F('bar_2'))
```

One uses an `F`-object to refer to a field. So `F('bar_2')` represents the `bar_2` field.